# FxCop warning won't go away

Tags: c#, marshalling, fxcop, structlayout

An object of this class will be passed to an API call. I implemented the first suggestion from the warning below:

> To reduce security risk, marshal field 'Resource.k__BackingField' 
>   as Unicode, by setting StructLayout.CharSet on 'Resource' 
>   to CharSet.Unicode, or by explicitly marshaling the 
>   field as UnmanagedType.LPWStr. If you need to marshal 
>   this string as ANSI or system-dependent, specify MarshalAs 
>   explicitly, use the BestFitMapping attribute to turn 
>   best-fit mapping off, and for added security, to turn 
>   ThrowOnUnmappableChar on.

Now my class looks similar to this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class Resource
{
    public string Provider;
}
```

But FxCop is still throwing the same warning. What does it want?

Comment: Side note: I'd expect fields instead of properties for object that is used for marshalling... At least it will make `LayoutKind.Sequential` to mean something (rather that let compiler to pick order of fields anyway)... and will give you better error to work with.

Comment: I am just playing. This will be a field in production. Trying to make the warning go away I also tried converting the field to a property. FxCop would then throw "Do not declare visible instance fields" but that's a non-issue.